# Deleting XML element nodes

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I want to delete an `Element Node` and all its `Child Elements` in a local xml-file by using C#.

This is my xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <cocktail name="43 Hedonism" id="14">
    <name>43 Hedonism</name>
    <id>14</id>
  </cocktail>
  <cocktail name="B-52" id="4">
    <name>B-52</name>
    <id>4</id>
  </cocktail>
</data>
```

I want to remove a cocktail Element where the id-attribute is 4, which is stored in a variable.
How can I tell my app that it only has to delete the cocktail Element where the id is 4?
`XmlNode.RemoveChild` will not work since it isn't supported/available in Windows Phone 8.
I wrote the following code but I'm stuck on where to write the id of the element I want to remove.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Resources;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using XmlLocalDelete1.Resources;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace XmlLocalDelete1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }

        private string id = "4";

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                tb1.Text = "";
                // copy the xml file to isolated storage
                using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (!file.FileExists("bar.xml"))
                    {
                        StreamResourceInfo sr_en = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources\\bar.xml", UriKind.Relative));
                        using (BinaryReader br_en = new BinaryReader(sr_en.Stream))
                        {
                            byte[] data = br_en.ReadBytes((int)sr_en.Stream.Length);
                            //Write the file.
                            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(file.CreateFile("bar.xml")))
                            {
                                bw.Write(data);
                                bw.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // work with file at isolatedstorage
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("bar.xml", FileMode.Open, file))
                    {
                        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream, LoadOptions.None);

                        // delete node
                        XElement deleteThis = doc.Element("cocktail");
                        deleteThis.Remove();
                    }

                    //  Write remaining Xml to textblock

                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("bar.xml", FileMode.Open, file))
                    {
                        //  Load the XML file
                        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            switch (reader.NodeType)
                            {
                                case XmlNodeType.Element: // Het knooppunt is een element.
                                    //tb1.Text = tb1.Text + "<" + reader.Name;
                                    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) // Attributen lezen.
                                        tb1.Text = tb1.Text + " " + reader.Name + "='" + reader.Value + "'";
                                    //tb1.Text = tb1.Text + ">";
                                    break;
                                case XmlNodeType.Text: //De tekst in elk element weergeven.
                                    //tb1.Text = tb1.Text + reader.Value + "\r\n";
                                    Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                                    break;
                                case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Het einde van het element weergeven.
                                    Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                                    Console.WriteLine(">");
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception myExc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myExc.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your xml really repeat the data as both attributes and elements?

Comment: Yes, it is. But as it appears, I'm still working on this.. ;)

Comment: Hopefully you are not partaking of the cocktails during this session (or then again maybe you should be!)

Answer (score 6):

> I want to remove a cocktail Element where the id-attribute is 4,

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename); //or XDocument.Load(stream);
xDoc.Descendants("cocktail").First(c => c.Attribute("id").Value == "4").Remove();
string newXml = xDoc.ToString();
```

OR using XPATH

```
xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//cocktail[@id='4']").Remove();
```

Comment: using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("bar.xml", FileMode.Open, file))
                    {
                        
                        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(stream, LoadOptions.None);
                        xDoc.Descendants("cocktail").First(c => c.Attribute("id").Value == "4").Remove();
                        //string newXml = xDoc.ToString();
                        xDoc.Save(stream);
                    } This isn't working. The node is still in the file..

Comment: @JelleKerkstra I tried above code with the xml you posted, it works.

Comment: This shows when I'm running: http://i811.photobucket.com/albums/zz38/JelleK1996/Screenshot47_zps4587160b.png

Comment: @JelleKerkstra put a breakpoint to `xdoc.Save` then see what you have.

Comment: http://i811.photobucket.com/albums/zz38/JelleK1996/delete1_zps7f04e50f.png and/or http://i811.photobucket.com/albums/zz38/JelleK1996/delete1_zps43ba9f09.png

Comment: @JelleKerkstra What is wrong? I don't see the node with id 4.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot I previously posted (http://i811.photobucket.com/albums/zz38/JelleK1996/Screenshot47_zps4587160b.png), it is still written to screen. I understand the modification is saved, but why does it look like it's still in the file when writing it to the textblock?

Comment: By adding a few breakpoints, I found out that `var xDoc = XDocument.Load(stream, LoadOptions.None);` is being executed but at the next line (`xDoc.Descendants("cocktail").First(c => c.Attribute("id").Value == "4").Remove();`), it moves to the `catch`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use XDocument instead XmlReader. In that case the task will be much easier.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
xdoc.Root.Elements().Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == "4").Remove();
xdoc.Save(filename);
```

Comment: Uh, I'm already using XDocument? XmlReader is used for writing the file to a textblock to check..

Comment: Oh, ok. I was inattentive. sorry for that. anyway the code works.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the XmlReader only for large xml files.
Searching and manipulation xml files is much easier with XmlDocument or better XDocument.