# How to remove xml element in windows phone

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

After I could create an xml, and adding data and element to it, I want to be able to remove a specific element from it as well. I tried to follow what it said from here [Deleting XML element nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892155/deleting-xml-element-nodes), then I could be able to remove any element from it; however, it does not remove that element completely; therefore, it's producing an error to my xml file.

My sample xml is like this (before removing)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--Favorite's xml-->
<favorites>
  <favorite id="1" pro_id="1" pro_name="Boots Expert Anti-Blemish Cleansing Foam" cate_xml="ProductsOily.xml" pro_image="images/Oily-Dry/BO001.JPG" />
  <favorite id="2" pro_id="2" pro_name="Clean &amp; Clear Advantage Oil Absorbing Cream Cleanser" cate_xml="ProductsOily.xml" pro_image="images/Oily-Dry/BP251.jpg" />
</favorites>
```

From example, I tried to remove an element that has `pro_id` equals 1, but my xml file, after remove, became like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--Favorite's xml-->
<favorites>
  <favorite id="2" pro_id="2" pro_name="Clean &amp; Clear Advantage Oil Absorbing Cream Cleanser" cate_xml="ProductsOily.xml" pro_image="images/Oily-Dry/BP251.jpg" />
</favorites>" pro_name="Clean &amp; Clear Advantage Oil Absorbing Cream Cleanser" cate_xml="ProductsOily
```

Here is my code to do this:

```
var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
fileName = "Favorite\\Favorite.xml";
XDocument docx = null;
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStreamx = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, storage))
{
   // isoStreamx.Position = 0;
    docx = XDocument.Load(isoStreamx);

    isoStreamx.SetLength(docx.ToString().Length);

    docx.Root.Elements().Where(x => x.Attribute("pro_id").Value == NavigationContext.QueryString["id"] as string).Remove();

    isoStreamx.Position = 0;
    docx.Save(isoStreamx);
}
```

How can I completely remove an element? Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently reusing the same stream to save over the top. That will only overwrite data - it won't truncate the file at the end point of your document. What you *really* want to do is effectively create a new file. Something like:

```
var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
fileName = "Favorite\\Favorite.xml";
XDocument docx = null;
using (var isoStreamx = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, storage))
{
    docx = XDocument.Load(isoStreamx);
}

var target = (string) NavigationContext.QueryString["id"];
docx.Root
    .Elements()
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("pro_id").Value == target)
    .Remove();

using (var isoStreamx = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, storage))
{
    docx.Save(isoStreamx);
}
```

You *could* keep your current code, and just call `isoStreamx.SetLength(isoStreamx.Position)` at the end (removing the current pointless and broken `SetLength` call) - but I think it's cleaner to use the code above.